# WinBUGs - Code for time series models

Tags: regression, bayesian, arima, bugs

I am looking to get started using time series (ARIMA, regression, etc.) evaluating logarithmic stock returns in WinBUGs.

Does anyone have a simple code to get me jump started?

Comment: Try asking a more specific question.  For something this general Google is probably a better bet.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question.  Only the 'etc' makes it really vague. 'What should I read on' and 'Where can I find code to do' questions seem to be pretty regularly asked and answered.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use WinBUGS? There are many alternatives that do ARIMA, ARCH, GARCH, etc. So my question is: are you wanting to do ARIMA, et al, or are you specifically looking for Bayesian tools to do ARIMA, et al, or are you definitely interested in WinBUGS?

Answer (score 3):

Congdon covers time series models (and WinBUGS code) in a chapter in his [Applied Bayesian Modelling](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471486957.html) book.

Alternatively, BUGS code for some time series models can be produced in my [tsbugs](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsbugs/index.html) package for R (and then run in BUGS via R2WinBUGS or similar such packages). Some of these are applied to the log of stock returns in the example code.